# Was there peace during the times of the first and second beis hamikdash

Tags: beis-hamikdash

During the times of the beis mikdash the nations of the world would bring peace offerings. Was there peace during those times throughout out the nations?

Answer (score 1):

During that time *individual* non-Jews could bring offerings, but I'm not aware of any nations bringing offerings regularly. As the book of Kings makes clear, there were many wars during the First Temple period. And there were many wars during the Second Temple (all of Alexander the Great, Hannukah, etc.) Peace offerings do not guarantee peace, they are called that because a portion is given to all parties (G-d "gets" the parts burned on the altar, the priests get a portion, and the bringer of the sacrifice gets the rest to eat with others.)